# 1から入力された整数値までの値を順に表示していくプログラムを、whileを使って作成したい

Tags: python

1から入力された整数値までの値を順に表示していくプログラムを、whileを使って作成したいのですが入力された値で止めるためにはどうしたらよいでしょうか？

コード

```
i = int(input('整数を入力：'))
while 1 <= i:
    print(i)
    i += 1
```

実行結果

```
整数を入力：5
1
2
3
4
5
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

カウンター変数と入力された値を格納する変数を分けてください。

```
i = int(input('整数を入力：'))
j = 1
while j <= i:
    print(j)
    j += 1
```

i 自体が `i += 1` でどんどん増えてしまうと、いつまで経っても終了条件に引っかからなくなります。